# Checkbox Quiz Multiple Choice

Tags: php, sql, arrays, post, checkbox

I am in the process of setting up a quiz which can have many answers for one question. The checkboxes are stored using an array and checked against my `answers_bank` table with the `ab_name` column (where the correct answers are stored).

All I am wanting to do is - if the answers which are checked are in the answers_bank table it echo's "correct", otherwise it echo's "incorrect" for the incorrect checked boxes.

The way I have tried to do it doesn't work, as it compares each individual answer in the array during each iteration and returns incorrect for the other answers (as it is not equal). This image should explain the issue I am having:

[image]

Here is a snippet of the code I have setup:

**Returns the checkbox questions as shown in the first part of the image:**

```
foreach ($qresults as $aresults) {
    $selected = $aresults["ab_name"];
    $ab_id = $aresults["ab_id"];
    ?>

    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]"
           value="<?php echo $aresults["ab_name"]; ?>"> <?php echo $aresults["ab_name"]; ?> <br>

    <?php
}
?>
```

**Aims to check if the answers are correct or not**

```
foreach ($results as $row) {

$qb_id = $row['qb_id'];
$q_answer = $_POST["q$qb_id"];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM answers_bank WHERE ab_qb_id = :qb_id AND ab_correct = :correct";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':qb_id', $qb_id);
$stmt->bindValue(':correct', "correct");
$stmt->execute();
$qresults = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach ($qresults as $cresults) {
    if (is_array($q_answer)) {
        foreach ($q_answer as $checkbox) {

            if ($checkbox == $cresults["ab_name"]) {
                echo "You said : " . $checkbox . " ... which is the correct answer!</br>";

            } else if ($checkbox != $cresults["ab_name"]) {
                echo "You said : " . $checkbox . " ... which is incorrect</br>";
            }

        }
    }
}
```

}

Any other solutions or corrections I can make to this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have a feeling we are missing some code, obviously the code checking the answer is called more than once.

Comment: @Epodax I have added more code to show how it checks against each answer in the db

Comment: You are using way too many loops, You need to remove one of the loops or Not have them loop inside each other. The reason this is happening is because you are first looping the database result, and each loop in there is a correct answer, you then proceed to loop through the POST data and echo out the "You said"..

Comment: It's just a question... contains answers.. which the answers contain arrays for the checkboxes it loops through each

Comment: Yes, and the way you do it right now, you will echo out all the possible answers for each right answer there is.

Comment: @Epodax Thanks, I understand that completely and how my foreach loops are setup incorrectly, I just can't figure out an alternative so that it returns echo's similar to the second example in the image

Comment: You might want to consider only checking the "correctness" of the answers  in your loops (and store a "checkmark" for those that are) and then echo the answers once your outside of the loops.

Comment: @Epodax I am still having issues with this, would you be able to explain further as this is driving me crazy! Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store all the correct answers first, so you don't have to loop over both them and the responses from the form.  Instead, you can just loop over the form responses and check whether the selected value is in the array of correct responses.

```
foreach ($results as $row) {

$qb_id = $row['qb_id'];
$q_answer = $_POST["q$qb_id"];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM answers_bank WHERE ab_qb_id = :qb_id AND ab_correct = :correct";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':qb_id', $qb_id);
$stmt->bindValue(':correct', "correct");
$stmt->execute();
$qresults = $stmt->fetchAll();

$correct_answers = array(); 
foreach ($qresults as $cresults) { 
    array_push($correct_answers, $cresults["ab_name"]);
} 

if (is_array($q_answer)) {
    foreach ($q_answer as $checkbox) {
        if (in_array($checkbox, $correct_answers)) {
            echo "You said : " . $checkbox . " ... which is the correct answer!</br>";
        } else {
            echo "You said : " . $checkbox . " ... which is incorrect</br>";
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I tried doing a nearly identical approach to this earlier. Turns out I was using my foreach loops incorrectly. This now works like a dream thank you!